# Explain alloc/init occurring twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I realize this question may sound dumb, but just bear with me. I built an app to help new developers wrap their head around memory retention on the iPhone (no ARC yet). It is plain and simple, 4 buttons, init, access, retain, and release. Pretty self explanatory. I am displaying what the retain count for my string object that is the target of our poking and prodding. (Please no lectures on use of [myVar retainCount], I already know)

This stuff will never make it into actual apps, just toying with it for fun and hopefully help someone learn how memory works. My retain and release all work great. My question is that why does my retain count drop back to 1 if I call myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; again. I can boost my retain count to 40, but after calling alloc/init I go back to zero. I am not leaking anywhere, just curious what happens to myString if/when alloc/init is called on it again.

Comment: Displaying the retain count, even in this limited of a context, is misleading.  If you do limit the use to the point that the retain count is accurate and understandable, you have so limited the scope that it is no longer representative of real world memory management.   Whatever your students might learn from this app will be useless when working on real apps.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read in the question, "Please no lectures on use of [myVar retainCount]."

Comment: @morningstar - Using `-retainCount` near bbum is like waving a red flag in front of a bull.

Comment: @morningstar The question itself has *nothing* to do with retainCount and the very fact that retainCount was brought into the mix indicated a lack of understanding of something very basic on Bill's part (no criticism intended -- we all started there).  If you note, my answer doesn't actually mention `retainCount` until the last paragraph of the new part.  As for the comment, well, it was a comment... not an answer.

Comment: Even if *you* understand `retainCount` fully and why it is misleading, using it to teach your students will teach *them* that `retainCount` is useful for learning and/or debugging. Better to remove the `retainCount` display in the app and use Instruments to view an object's history live as you hit the buttons: then you teach them a useful debugging technique and don't implicitly teach them to use `retainCount`.

Comment: This is what I knew would happen. I know all about retain count. I know that it can never return zero. And to @bbum last tip on retain count, that is exactly how this is being treated. As dumb as my question may have sounded, I know what I'm doing within the scope of my training app. Thank you all for the feedback, it has been enlightening.

Comment: See, that's kinda the point... if you are creating a training app that shows the absolute retain count, then most of us with many years [or decades] of experience are going to crawl out of the woodwork and lecture you on retainCount because many of us went down the same path and are trying to save you the pain.

Comment: I appreciate the concern, but my intent isn't to show absolute anything, retain count or otherwise. Just a quick little app that shows what happens when you retain, release, and try to access memory that has been released. The use of retain count is irrelevant to what I'm trying to show.

Comment: BTW:  If you are going to definitely show what happens when you try to access memory that has been deallocated, you should either turn on MALLOC_SCRIBBLE or otherwise "corrupt" the memory on deallocation (i.e. write garbage into it *before* it is free()d.  If you don't do that, you'll likely end up with code that doesn't crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [myString retainCount]); // "1"
for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
    [myString retain];
NSLog(@"%d", [myString retainCount]); // "40"

NSString *backup = myString;
myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [myString retainCount]); // "1"
NSLog(@"%d", [backup retainCount]); // "40"
```

You see, you have a different object with a new retain count. Your original object still exists and still has the same retain count. Assignment changes the object a variable refers to. A variable doesn't have a retain count, an object does.

```
myString = someOtherString;
NSLog(@"%d", [myString retainCount]); // who knows?
```

With retained property:

```
self.iString = backup;
NSLog(@"%d", [self.iString retainCount]); // "41" - 1 more because property retained
NSString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [newString retainCount]); // "1"
self.iString = newString;
// 1 for alloc 1 for retain (in real code you should release newString next)
NSLog(@"%d", [self.iString retainCount]); // "2"
NSLog(@"%d", [backup retainCount]); // "40" - self.iString released it
```

Comment: Would this idea change on a (nonatomic, retain) property? Or same principal?

Comment: It causes some retain and release messages to be sent, but it's still a variable. A retain property will cause the counts to differ by 1 one way or the other, but not change the fact that the retain count can change by 40 at a time for a _variable_. I am adding an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps. I may build some of this into my app to help convey this. Much appreciated.

Comment: This could be more effectively demonstrated without `retainCount` and the use of `retainCount` as an absolute count is misleading.

Answer (score 28):

> My question is that why does my retain count drop back to 1 if I call
>   `myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` again?

Because you are failing to understand a very basic concept of Objective-C;   `myString` is not an instance of an `NSMutableString`, but a reference to an instance.   If you were to:

```
myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

You now have two instances of NSMutableString, one leaked.

If you:

```
myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
otherString = myString;
```

You now have a single instance of NSMutableString with two references.

In all three allocations, the NSMutableString instance will have a +1 retain count and, thus, you must balance each with a single `release` or you'll leak.

Treating retain counts as an absolute count is a path to madness.  Or, at best, the scope of usefulness of the absolute retain count is so limited that learning about it is not applicable to real world iOS programming.

---

This bears repeating:

The `retainCount` of an object is tricky business.

If you were to continue down this path, you should be aware of the following details:

- `retainCount` can never return 0
- messaging a dangling pointer is not guaranteed to crash
- retain count cannot be known once you have passed an object through any system API due to implementation details
- any subclass of any system class may have an unknown retain count due to implementation details
- retain count never reflects whether or not an object is autoreleased
- autoreleases is effectively thread specific while the retain count is thread global
- some classes are implemented with singletons some of the time (NSString, certain values of NSNumber)
- the implementation details change from platform to platform and release to release
- attempting to swizzle `retain`/`release`/`autorelease` won't work as some classes don't actually use those methods to maintain the retain count (implementation detail, changes per platform/release, etc..)

If you are going to teach retain/release, you should be treating the retain count as a delta and focus entirely on "If you increase the RC, you must decrease it".

Answer (score 11):

when you call `myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`, you're not "calling alloc/init on it again". You're not calling a method on the same instance you had. You're allocating and initializing a new instance, a completely different object from the one you had before.

And if you're doing that with a variable that had an object that you retained, then yes, you are leaking it.

Comment: You can see the leak if you run the app in Instruments with the Leak profile.  This is the classic C pointer confusion - your variable is  pointer to allocated memory.  If you allocate new memory and update your pointer to the new memory without first flagging to the system that you are done with the previous allocation, it is leaked (as filipe says).